# How can you calculate the multiplicative inverse using euclidean algorithm (I tried on an example)?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I'd finally like to know the exact way how it's done, if it's possible at all. I know sometimes it might be better to avoid euclid but I have to know how it's done by using this.

Here is an example I made myself and I hope it's a good one.

> Find the multiplicative inverse of $11$ in $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$

We can also write: $\text{ gcd }(11,12)=1$

$$12=11\cdot1+1$$

$$11=1 \cdot 11+0$$

Now $1=12-11\cdot 1$

I don't think we can do anything from here now.. But what does this tell us, what's the multiplicative inverse now? How can we know it from this notation? Did I do it correct at all? Please do tell me!

Comment: So, you already have found such an $x$ that $11x\equiv 1\pmod{12}$.

Comment: I don't understand : / How do you know from my solution above what the multiplicative inverse of $11$ is? What is it?

Comment: $1=12-11\cdot 1$ is the same as $-1\cdot 11=1-12$, and it is the same as $-1\cdot 11\equiv 1\pmod {12}$

Comment: This special case can be solved much easier considering $11\equiv -1\mod 12$. It is not hard to find the multiplicative inverse of $-1$

Comment: Nothing helps me so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the multiplicative inverse of $a $ modulus $m $ is finding the solution to $ax \equiv 1 \mod m $

We know that equation has a solution iff $\gcd(a, m) $ divides 1, which implies $\gcd(a, m) = 1$

If that is the case, then from the euclidean algorithm to find the gcd you know you can have

$$1 = x_0a + y_0m $$

With $x_0, y_0 $ integers. Right?
But taking that modulus $m $ we get

$$1 \equiv x_0a + y_0m \mod m \iff 1 \equiv x_0a \mod m$$

And thus $x_0$ is $a $'s multiplicative inverse.

For your specific case we have $\gcd(11, 12) = 1$ so 11 has a multiplicative inverse. From the euclidean algorithm we can see, as you wrote, that $1 = 1\cdot12 - 1\cdot11$.

Here we have $x_0 = -1$ and $y_0 = 1$. So it follows that $x_0 = -1$ is the multiplicative inverse of 11 modulus 12:

$$-1 \equiv 11 \mod 11 \Rightarrow (-1)\cdot11 \equiv 1 \mod 12 \iff (11)\cdot11 \equiv 1 \mod 12 \iff 121 \equiv 1 \mod 12$$

But $121 = 10\cdot12 + 1 \Rightarrow 121 \equiv 1 \mod12$ showing that 11 is its own multiplicative inverse.

Comment: So it's not possible to directly read from this what the multiplicative inverse of $11$ is?: $$1=12 - 11 \cdot 1$$

Comment: @berdgr it is possible. Just put the coefficient *before* the 11 and not after: $1 = 12 - 1\cdot11$ thus (-1) is 11's inverse

Comment: So -1 and 11 are multiplicative inverse of 11?