# Find the additive inverse of $[33]_{60}$ in $(\mathbb{Z} / 60,+)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Find the additive inverse of $[33]_{60}$ in $(\mathbb{Z} / 60,+)$.

[image]

In my textbook there is a theorem I can use to find the multiplicative inverse. But I could not find any result which I can use to find the additive inverse. 
It's a multiple choice and I have six choices I can choose from, but that will be just guesswork.

Which mathematical results and definitions should I use?

Comment: It is simply $-33=27$. For the multiplicative inverse see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010418/how-can-you-calculate-the-multiplicative-inverse-using-euclidean-algorithm-i-tr).

Comment: You can also solve $$x+33=60$$ giving $\ x=27\ $. Note that $\ 87\ $ also works because it gives the same residue if divided by $\ 60\ $.

Comment: Several people giving out full answers in the comment section here, apparently.

Comment: Hint: it must end with either $3$ or $7$

Comment: @Arthur I rarely post trivial answers just to collect reputation points.

Comment: @Peter post the answer as community wiki, so the question gets an answer and you don't get trivial "points"

Comment: @Peter It's not about the points. It's about getting the question marked as answered (and also comments are explicitly not meant to be where you answer a question, it even says "Avoid answering questions in comments" in the comment box itself). If you're worried about getting too many points, then you can tag it as community wiki, and you will get no points.

Comment: @Arthur I will remember it in future :)

Comment: The additive inverse is just the complement to $60$ (so it might be learnt  at the beginning of elementary school!).

Comment: @Peter I don't think one should give an answer without suggesting to the OP to try something himself. After a small hint in the comments I would rather close the question than writing a full answer (except of course when the OP shows some efforts).

Answer (score 2):

HINT:
You can obtain the inverse of $x$ by subtracting it from the modulus as:
$$x+(n-x) = n = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of theorems you can use ( however advanced):

***The inverse ( additive or multiplicative) modulo a composite number $n$ is also a valid inverse modulo the prime powers dividing $n$***

This can be coupled with the theorem below:

**Chinese remainder theorem/generalization**: There exists a remainder modulo the lcm of moduli, for any set of remainders modulo the moduli . This can be found by turning them into linear form, and setting them equal to solve.

**Note** : the first theorem can be generalized to quadratic residues, and coprime residues, etc.

**EDIT** :Here's another one any time a multiplicative inverse $x$ exists, Letting $y$ be the additive inverse:  $$xy\equiv-1$$ The real uselessness is a multiplicative inverse need not always exist, while the additive inverse always exists in the more general settings.

Comment: yet not generators, as unless the lcm of their orders is $n-1$ it fails to be a generator ( though a highest order value) for mod $n$